# How to create a mobile website from scratch

Tags: mobile

I have created a small application. How can I create a mobile version of the same website? Mobile development is very new to me so I would prefer a step by step instructions on how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Identify only the crucial elements on the webpages, get rid of the rest.
2. Make sure that the elements are big enough to be navigated/clicked by finger as there is no mouse pointer.
3. Make sure that there is enough space between the elements, again the user will be using his finger and not the mouse.
4. Size the webpage to 100% width and height to automatically fit any browser on any mobile device and resolution.
5. Upon user webpage request, detect if it is a mobile device and redirect to the mobile version you have just created.

Now, the really difficult part is to decide if you want the same webpage to display differently on desktop and mobile, or if you want to create a separate pages for desktop and mobile.
The best solution is to use the same page and output a different content by detecting the requesting device, but it is up to you to decide.